# How can I check if a table contains the selected number?

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, listbox, primary-key

I have 2 tables in my database. In my application I can select a record (customer) and link it to a order. I also have an option to remove customers, but when I remove a customer with a link to an order, it crashes. How can I do a check if the ID of the selected item from a listbox exists in the order table? I want it to show a error messagebox.

This is my code so far:

```
reservering deResv = new reservering();

var item = (chalet)lbHuis.SelectedItem;

if (deResv.HuisId == item.Id)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Verwijder eerst de reserveringen van dit huis.");
        }
        else
        {

            var delItem = from chalet in db.chalets
                          where chalet.Id == item.Id
                          select chalet;


            db.chalets.DeleteOnSubmit(item);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

reservering is the name of the order table.

chalet is the name of the (in this case) property table. this acts the same as a customer table.

lbHuis is the name of the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

I would query the table you have for storing your ordering items before attempting the delete so you can show that error message you want to. A method i've used in the past would look like the following:

```
int foundID = -1;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<your connection string>")) 
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id FROM reserving WHERE id=@orderID;", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderID", item.Id);
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            foundID = reader["id"];
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Isnt there a way to replace deResv.HuisId with something?

Comment: What do you want deResv.HuisId to store? Does the constructor for reserving() assign it an ID?

You could just compare foundID == item.ID. You could make my sql statement a little better by adding another variable to make sure that user is connected with a reservation with that item ID